# Spring data storage: xml and database

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I need to use database or xml file for storing data. How can I do this with Spring? 
App read property file and choose which data storage use.

Comment: This is probably a good start: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html

Comment: And what's about xml as database?

Comment: Probably you have good reasons to use xml as database, but I have never used it.